# Sonata AdminBundle, get the parameter of an entity

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I have an entity Prototype with a relation many to one with project and I want to override a function in the CRUDController.

Here is the code :

```
$idPrototype = $this->get('request')->get($this->admin->getIdParameter());
```

I get the id of the prototype, but I want the parameter 'project' ( the id of the project ) 
Here is my prototype entity

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Prototype
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\PrototypeRepository")
 */
class Prototype
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nom;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dateCreation", type="date")
 */
private $dateCreation;

private $projet;


public function __construct()
{   
    $this->dateCreation =  new \DateTime("now");
    $this->nom = "";
    $this->description = " ";
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}


/**
 * Get nom
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getNom()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

public function __toString()
{
return $this->getNom();
}

/**
 * Set nom
 *
 * @param string $nom
 * @return Prototype
 */
public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}


/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 * @return Prototype
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set dateCreation
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateCreation
 * @return Prototype
 */
public function setDateCreation($dateCreation)
{
    $this->dateCreation = $dateCreation;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateCreation
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDateCreation()
{
    return $this->dateCreation;
}


/**
 * Set projet
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Projet $projet
 * @return Prototype
 */
public function setProjet(\AppBundle\Entity\Projet $projet = null)
{
    $this->projet = $projet;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get projet
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Projet 
 */
public function getProjet()
{
    return $this->projet;
}

}
```

I've tried to use ModelManager() but I get this error "Attempted to call an undefined method named "getModelManager" of class "AppBundle\Controller\CRUDProtoController". " 
I'm new with sonata and symfony and I find difficulties with it.

Comment: You can still get your project from prototype curd controller object something like `$object->getProject()->getId()`

Comment: thank you very much ! it woorks